# R directory path windows vs Mac

Tags: r, windows, macos, portability

I have a number of R Projects which run on my Windows machine and I recently bought a Mac.

I would like to alternate between my Mac and Windows pc without changing code snippets all the time.

I use variables that serve as directory/path locations.

For example:

```
temp_path <- 'C:/RCode/'
```

If I run this code on my Mac, I will obviously get an error.

How can I get around this?

Comment: stick to relative paths as much as you can. Also i believe `path.expand('~')` will work with `C://` on windows?

Comment: Thanks I will research relative paths

Comment: changing to a relative path mindset helped my project organization enormously! a primer https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/

Comment: Possibly check out the `here` package. Here's a intro: https://github.com/jennybc/here_here

Answer (score 2):

You can specify path based on OS using an if condition. To find the OS you can use *.Platform$OS.type. 
Here is a sample code to make it work.

```
OS <- .Platform$OS.type

if (OS == "unix"){
  temp_path <- "~/RCode/" # MAC file path
} else if (OS == "windows"){
  temp_path <- "C:/RCode/" # windows file path
} else {
  print("ERROR: OS could not be identified")
}
```